# TinyButStrong Block Not Working for li tag

Tags: tinybutstrong

If I define my block on the li tag, TBS only shows the first item in the array.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Logs<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a class="file" href="/logs/#[logs.key; block=li]">[logs.key]</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/logs/#" id="grepKeyword" class="nav-link">Settings</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><span class="navbar-text" id="grepspan"></span></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><span class="navbar-text" id="invertspan"></span></li>
</ul>
```

If I define the block on the a tag, it shows all the items in the array.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Logs<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <a class="file" href="/logs/#[logs.key; block=a]">[logs.key]</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/logs/#" id="grepKeyword" class="nav-link">Settings</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><span class="navbar-text" id="grepspan"></span></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><span class="navbar-text" id="invertspan"></span></li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Both snippets are merged as expected. Can you send to me a small template + script that reproduces the bug ?

Comment: I placed template and script here: https://pastebin.com/j205ctka